# Iterating over a directory of files using GNU Make

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

My project has a directory called `tests/` which contains an arbitrary number of C source files, each one is a self-contained program designed to test a library. For each of these sourcefiles, I want to create an executable of the same name in my `build/` directory.

E.g. `tests/test_init.c` would compile to an executable file `build/test_init`.

Currently, my Makefile snippet looks like the following:

```
BUILD_DIR = build
TEST_DIR = tests

test_sources:= $(TEST_DIR)/*.c
test_executables:= $(patsubst %.c, %, $(test_sources))

.PHONY: tests

tests: $(test_executables)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ -g
```

But this fails to produce to desired result. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need the [wildcard function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) to find the sources:

```
test_sources:= $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/*.c)
```

Then the correct names for the executables:

```
test_executables:= $(patsubst $(TEST_DIR)/%.c, $(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(test_sources))
```

Then a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) to build a test executable from the corresponding source:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%: $(TEST_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@ -g
```

(A [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) might be a little tidier, but it's a more advanced method.)

Finally a [phony](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) target to build all of the tests:

```
.PHONY: tests
tests: $(test_executables)
```

If you wanted Make to *run* all of these tests, you could make a phony pattern rule `run_test_%`, but that can wait for another day.

Answer (score 0):

This Makefile will detect all files in `test/*.c` and provides tasks `build_tests`, `run_tests`, and `clean_tests`.

```
all: build_tests

define test_template

build_tests: test/$(1)

run_tests: build_tests run_test_$(1)

test/$(1) : test/$(1).c
    $$(CC) $$^ -o $$@

.PHONY : run_test_$(1)
run_test_$(1) : test/$(1)
    test/$(1)

endef

clean: clean_tests

clean_tests:
    rm -fv $(foreach test, $(tests),test/$(test))

# Auto detect the tests (any .c file in the test directory),
# and store the list of tests names.
tests := $(foreach test, $(wildcard test/*.c),$(patsubst %.c,%,$(notdir $(test))))

# Add information about each test to the Makefile.
$(foreach test, $(tests), $(eval $(call test_template,$(test))))
```

Note: I'm not sure how to get tabs working inside a code block in markdown, so you'll need to replace spaces with a single tab on each indented line if you copy and paste this.